# Method level Generic Typing for flatMap

Tags: java, oop, functional-programming, stream, lazy-evaluation

I am currently working on a `SpecialList` implementation of a lazy stream and am required to implement the flatmap feature.

```
public <R> SpecialList<R> flatMap(Function<T, SpecialList<R>> mapper) {
    return new SpecialList<R>(() -> mapper.apply(this.content));
}
```

This means that I'd take in a function of type T and return a SpecialList of type R.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
SpecialList.java:43: error: no suitable constructor found for SpecialList(()->mapper[...]y(ts))
        return new SpecialList<R>(() -> mapper.apply(this.content));
               ^
    constructor SpecialList.SpecialList(R) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; R is not a functional interface)
    constructor SpecialList.SpecialList(Supplier<R>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
          SpecialList<R> cannot be converted to R)
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>flatMap(Function<T,SpecialList<R>>)
    T extends Object declared in class SpecialList
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

I have a SpecialList() constructor taking in a value, but since my return type is now 'R' it doesn't seem to be working, and they say that no suitable constructor is found.

Shouldn't the 'R' type be replaced and become the T in the constructor? Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: generic type parameter

Comment: I've been searching, but I only find info on the ones with one <R>, not the one before the return type.

Comment: Generic type parameters can be declared either on the class level or on the method level. In the case of the method level, they are declared before the return type of the method, as in `<R> SpecialList<R> flatMap()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the argument passed to the constructor:

`() -> mapper.apply(this.content)` has a type of `Supplier<SpecialList<R>>`, and not `R` neither `Specialist<R>`.

It's difficult to understand what is exactly your intention, but if you simply rewrite the method like this, it should compile:

```
public <T, R> SpecialList<R> flatMap(Function<T, SpecialList<R>> mapper) {
    return mapper.apply(this.content);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your response! Basically, my flatMap must return another SpecialList with the content contained inside. I can't publicly post my source as this is a homework and I just wanted some clarification on that. It's still not working, but I'm trying!